# How to dynamically change the page title every 2 seconds using Ajax & Jquery? (Firefox not Working?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm trying to change the page title to something new every 2 seconds. The following Javascript code works in Chrome, however in Firefox, the new page title only stays for less than a second and then the title reverts back to the original page title. How do I get the new, update page title to stay put and not revert to the original in Firefox?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshit = setInterval(updatePageTitle, 2000);
});
function updatePageTitle(){
    var url = "http://www.website.com/page.php?action=title&rand="+ Math.random();   

    $.post( url, function(data) {

        document.title = data;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Well, not that I expect this to fix it, but you're missing the closing `);` after your `}` under the `var refreshit = ` line.

Comment: Yes, Deryck, sorry, I didn't transfer the closing ); to the code here, but it is there in my code on the server. So, no, that didn't fix it, but thanks. :)

Comment: @Mandiana - so please use the edit button on your question to fix the syntax error so you don't keep getting comments/answers related to it.

Comment: I don't know what's causing the issue, but I see a potential problem with timing.  You're firing a timer every two seconds, but not changing the title until after an ajax call responds which will be some amount of time later.  This is not very predictable timing.  It might be better if you use `setTimeout()` to run the ajax call, then when the ajax call responds, you set the title and set the next `setTimeout()`.  This will guarantee that you never get multiple ajax calls backed up in flight at the same time if they get slow.

Comment: Do you have any other refresh logic in the page that might be doing a meta refresh or reloading the page?

Comment: There is javascript from cometchat on the page. A quick search of the cometchat javascript shows they are doing a lot of setInterval stuff, but what exactly, I'm not sure. I don't think anything is reloading the whole page. What really confuses me is, why would it work in Chrome, but not in Firefox?

Comment: @Mandiana - I don't see anything in the javascript you've shown us that would reset the title.  Something else in the page must be causing it.

Comment: Okay, @jfriend00, I'll keep looking. Thanks for taking the time to investigate and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I was using was correct. The problem was there was an external script changing it back to the original title.